# iOS - copy a CALayer in ViewdidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation

I got a CALayer and I want to copy it into 5 or more CALayers in ViewdidLoad is there is a possible way to do this. Here is my layer:

```
alye = [CALayer layer];
alye.position = CGPointMake(129, 189);
alye.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, theHeight/13.45, theWidth/2.66);
alye.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
alye.opacity = 0.6f;
[self.view.layer addSubLayer:alye];
```

Any help please? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "copy"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @coneybeare I'm sorry, I'm new to iOS development, I can't unsderstand the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create multiple duplicates of a layer, take a look at a CAReplicatorLayer. That lets you create multiple copies of a source layer, applying a transform to each copy.